# Why internet is not working on React preview link?

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I have connected my mobile to the same wifi router which my laptop also connected. So we can open the react application in mobile browser as well. But the problem is server API calls are not working. Eg: Login not working. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you remember to open port 3000 to external network traffic on the device running the local development server?

Comment: @DrewReese Im not sure. How to do that?

Comment: Depends on your OS and any security software you may be running, google "open port on [your OS]". It usually involves going to your firewall settings and adjusting settings for port and/or app access, in & out.